# Is there a way to add group names before executing a test in TestNG (Java)?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

For each test (@Test) we have to add group names dynamically before executing them.
Before executing @Test method, data provider is invoked and it will give the list of group names to that particular test case falls in.

Is there any way to add group names to @Test before executing them?
Based on the group name which we pass from testng.xml should run only those cases.
Please guide me if we have any existing solution for this use case.

Comment: To "add group names" to where? For what? What is the final goal?

Comment: Adding group names to a @Test before executing it. And we are passing the test data from CSV file. Where the CSV file contains the group info the test case. Final goal is to run the specific GROUP of test cases from testng.